# how to manage header of first page and rest of the pages differently

Tags: header-footer

I want different header of first page of the article and on rest of the pages I want author name and article name to appear alternately.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package and a conditional test for the page number; something like this:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\def\Author{The Author}
\def\Title{The Title}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EC]{\Author}
\fancyhead[OC]{
\ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
Header for the first page
\else
\Title
\fi}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, no MWE was provided, so we don't know whether `\maketitle` is being used, in which case some modification will have to be done to let the `plain` style used by the page with the title use the `fancy` style; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}% just to generate text for the example

\def\Author{The Author}
\def\Title{The Title}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EC]{\Author}
\fancyhead[OC]{
\ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
Header for the first page
\else
\Title
\fi}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@fancy
\makeatother

\author{\Author}
\title{\Title}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```